# iOS Pasteboard strange random crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchdog, xpc, pasteboard

Our app received the crash multi times due to use Pasteboard. Under this situation when I try to use system Notes paste the content, the system notes will block too. So I write a program try to read the pasteboard, but it will also crash when I use [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard].

I'm sure this seriou bug is apple's bug, all the app will crash when launch under this situation If use UIPasteboard class. When I reboot the phone, it's ok. I have report this issue to apple but no reply, very disappointed.

```
Date/Time: 2018-12-19 11:37:49.4053 +0800
Launch Time: 2018-12-19 11:37:29.3603 +0800
OS Version: iPhone OS 12.1 (16B92)
Baseband Version: 3.11.00
Report Version: 104

Exception Type: EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note: EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Reason: Namespace SPRINGBOARD, Code 0x8badf00d
Termination Description: SPRINGBOARD, scene-create watchdog transgression: com.xxxxx.xxxx exhausted real (wall clock) time allowance of 19.86 seconds | ProcessVisibility: Background | ProcessState: Running | WatchdogEvent: scene-create | WatchdogVisibility: Foreground | WatchdogCPUStatistics: ( | "Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 14.230 (user 14.230, system 0.000), 18% CPU", | "Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 0.005, 0% CPU" | )
Triggered by Thread: 0

Thread 0 name: Dispatch queue: com.apple.UIKit.pasteboard.cache-queue
Thread 0 Crashed:
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x00000001eb35bed0 mach_msg_trap + 8
1 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x00000001eb35b3a8 mach_msg + 72
2 libdispatch.dylib 0x00000001eb1db614 _dispatch_mach_send_and_wait_for_reply + 500
3 libdispatch.dylib 0x00000001eb1dbab4 dispatch_mach_send_with_result_and_wait_for_reply$VARIANT$armv81 + 56
4 libxpc.dylib 0x00000001eb422eb4 xpc_connection_send_message_with_reply_sync + 204
5 Foundation 0x00000001ec393a28 __NSXPCCONNECTION_IS_WAITING_FOR_A_SYNCHRONOUS_REPLY__ + 12
6 Foundation 0x00000001ec15b4dc -[NSXPCConnection _sendInvocation:orArguments:count:methodSignature:selector:withProxy:] + 3632
7 CoreFoundation 0x00000001eb7d5460 ___forwarding___ + 556
8 CoreFoundation 0x00000001eb7d745c _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 92
9 Pasteboard 0x0000000200c29778 -[PBServerConnection pasteboardWithName:createIfNeeded:error:] + 688
10 Pasteboard 0x0000000200c2949c -[PBServerConnection pasteboardWithName:error:] + 96
11 UIKitCore 0x00000002187b5d90 _pasteboardCacheQueue_existingItemCollectionWithName + 896
12 UIKitCore 0x00000002187b57d8 __59+[_UIConcretePasteboard _pasteboardNamed:createIfNotFound:]_block_invoke + 228
13 libdispatch.dylib 0x00000001eb20a484 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
14 libdispatch.dylib 0x00000001eb1ea754 _dispatch_lane_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete + 56
15 UIKitCore 0x00000002187b5630 +[_UIConcretePasteboard _pasteboardNamed:createIfNotFound:] + 332
16 UIKitCore 0x00000002187b4b00 +[UIPasteboard _pasteboardWithName:create:] + 148
```

Comment: Having a similar problem since iOS13 SDK, though not directly accessing the pasteboard, setting focus on a UISearchBar seems to have the same effect.  I take it you have not heard back yet from apple?

Comment: Also just seen this in an Ionic capacitor app when the keyboard shows from a <input> focus (Xcode 11.1).  As Vladex says restarting simulator fixes this issue, only seen on simulator so far, was that stack trace simulator?

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar issue with a search bar (in different view controllers).
Quit the ios simulator and launch it again, it helps me.

Comment: Fixes things for me, though i *think* afei's stack trace is on target device (due to being ejected by springboard)

Comment: Experienced the same problem out of the blue, except in the context of making a UITextField the first responder.  This solution worked for me.  Reminds me of troubleshooting my grandmother's computer problems:  step one, turn it off and turn it back on!  Thanks.